# Blazor (Server-Side) Sidebar Compatability Issues in IE 11

Tags: bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11, sidebar

I've been working with Blazor Apps recently (server-side) and noticed that IE 11 Support needs Polyfill for some features that aren't supported.

Although I've applied the necessary dependencies to make this work, my sidebar on IE 11 is behaving in a very different way than the other browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox).

When I scroll my "main" content, the side bar is going upwards and leaving a huge blank space in the rest of the page.

Did anyone experienced this? (Note: Didn't change any code regarding the Frontend...)

```
Update:

    <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img src="../images/hightide-logo.png" width="80" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" style="margin-top: -5px">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="contact-us">
                <span class="material-icons">email</span> Contact us
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
        <LoginDisplay />
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4 mt-2">
        @Body
    </div>

    <LayoutFooter>
        <!-- Footer Goes Here -->
    </LayoutFooter>
</div>



.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}

    .sidebar .top-row {
        background-color: #f4f5f7;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    .sidebar .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }

    .sidebar .oi, .sidebar .material-icons {
        width: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        vertical-align: text-top;
        top: -2px;
    }

    .sidebar .nav-item {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

        .sidebar .nav-item:first-of-type {
            padding-top: 1rem;
        }

        .sidebar .nav-item:last-of-type {
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
        }

        .sidebar .nav-item a {
            color: #d7d7d7;
            border-radius: 4px;
            height: 3rem;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            line-height: 3rem;
        }

            .sidebar .nav-item a.active {
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
                color: white;
            }

            .sidebar .nav-item a:hover {
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
                color: white;
            }
```

[image: Sidebar Issue]

Comment: Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your description and the picture, I suppose perhaps you are using the CSS Flexible Box Layout, from [this link](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex), we can see it is partial support IE browser.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFTthanks for your help. I've put the razor page code and the css classes. I hope it's enough :) I'm very happy on working with Blazor apps, it was a big boost from WebForms!

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, I have tried to create a new Blazor Application and use your code in the MainLayout.razor component, the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMCdy.png), it sees that everything works well in the IE browser.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT thanks for your feedback, Did you tried to create more content inside the rendered pages (Body) ? When the scroll appears on the browser, it's like the sidebar doesn't have enoug height to cover the rest of the height. (I don't know if I explained correctly)

Comment: please check my reply, whether the issue is related to the height property in the site.css file, and after removing the height property and adding the bottom  property, whether it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the scroll appears, the web page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KFGa.gif). If this is the problem, to make the sidebar cover the rest of the height. You can change the sidebar CSS style as below (set the **bottom** property):

```
.sidebar {
     width: 250px; 
     position: sticky; 
     top: 0px; 
     bottom: 0px;
}
```

[**Note**] You should also change the `.sidebar` css style in the **site.css** file, and for the `.sidebar` CSS style in the media query, also need to remove the height property, like this:

[image]

Then, the output like this.

[image]

Comment: This answer couldn't be better. Thanks for the explanation! :)